# very new to python would appreciate

Tags: python

I'm in a python class with a dumb teacher and I havent been able to get anything to work right. Here's a simple program i'm just trying to get to work once i know it doesn't really gget the average.

```
>>> class two:
    def average(a,b):
        return int((a+b)/2)
    def main():
        num = input("Number? ")
        x= int(num)
        y= average(x+1,x)
        print(y)
    main()


Number? 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    class two:
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 9, in two
    main()
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 7, in main
    y= average(x+1,x)
NameError: global name 'average' is not defined
```

Comment: This is a Q&A site, where is the question?

Comment: @sashoalm: Why does the error happen?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the program doen't work and gives me that error

Comment: May I recommend [The Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/)?

Comment: @BrandonJohnson - You may be wondering why you received so many negative votes. I suspect it is because you didn't ask a question. StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site. People, such as yourself, who need assistance ask questions and other readers answer them. In your case, you haven't asked a question; both of your sentences are declarative. A good, specific question would be like "Why isn't `average` defined?" or "How do I invoke a class method?" When you ask a specific question, we gain insight into what specifically you understand and what we need to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error happens because you do not have any global name `average` in scope when you use it. 
You seem to be confused about when and whether to use the `class` keyword. In your particular example, you don't need it -- both `average` and `main` want to be global functions, not class methods.

Try this program instead:

```
def average(a,b):
    return int((a+b)/2)
def main():
    num = input("Number? ")
    x= int(num)
    y= average(x+1,x)
    print(y)
main()
```

Alternatively, if you want to learn about classes:

```
class two:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def average(self):
        return (self.x + self.y)/2
def main():
    t = two(7,42)
    print(t.average())

main ()
```

Notice how the declaration of `average` now includes a `self` parameter -- this links the call to a particular `two` object. Notice also how the invocation of `average` changed: it is now `t.average()`. In this case, `t` is the specific object which will be passed as the first parameter of `two.average()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def average(a,b):
    return int((a+b)/2)

def main():
    print 'enter a number'
    num = raw_input()
    y = average(int(num)+1,int(num))
    print y

main()
```

Comment: FYI, you have provided an answer which works in Python2, but the OP seems to be using Python3.